# Changing the username in terminal in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: username

I recently purchased a second hand Dell Latitude laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 installed in it. After playing around with it, I've managed to change the hostname of the computer, such that it displays my name as the hostname. I mean- when I open the terminal, I get: `user1@Manish_Giri:~$`

My question is - how do I change the part which says "user1"? I'm not sure if this part is the "username", because my username as displayed in `System Settings > User Accounts > My Account` is something else. Here's a screenshot.

[image]

I'd rather have my name displayed as the username part in terminal, instead of "user1". I've no idea how to modify this. Can someone please help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal do:

```
sudo usermod -l newname oldname
```